# Caroufredsel image slider - get the number of the visible slide

Tags: jquery, carousel, caroufredsel

I'm using the [CarouFredSel](http://caroufredsel.dev7studios.com/) slider on one of my projects. Is there a way to get the index/number of the slide which is currently visible? I need to show something like - slide 2 of 10 and change the number accordingly when the slide is changed.

Didn't find such an option in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation

> currentPosition ( fn )
>
> Triggering this event will return the position of the first visible item (the current position) in the callback-function or (when calling the triggerHandler-method) the return value.

http://caroufredsel.dev7studios.com/custom-events.php

Comment: Using this answer, I have set up a single slide slideshow with a separate multiple side carousel. onBefore on the single slide slideshow with currentPosition gets the index. I can then set an active state on the carousel. Perfect, how i missed this in the docs I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy:

```
var currentPage = $('ul#foo').triggerHandler("currentPage");
var currentPosition = $('ul#foo').triggerHandler("currentPosition");
```